# Password reset mail - reset password again

Tags: password-reset

Let's assume this situation: I am a user of an online shop, I forgot my password. So I use the functionality of this online shop to reset my password. The online shop sends me an email with a link I should visit to change my password. I changed my password, but did not delete this email.

Now, a day later (after this passwod reset) I saw this email again and clicked again on it and I can change my password again. From a security perspective: How would you value this situation?

Comment: I feel like the linked question is asking a related question but still essentially answers the question you've asked.  If you don't agree please edit and clarify what it is you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

If you can do that, it means that the developers didn't use a token to only make valid that link for a certain time.

The right solution is to use tokens that will expire either after the password has been reset or after 10-15 mins.

Answer (score 2):

This situation has a security risk in it as if any other person can get hold of this link he can change your password and use your account in not a desirable way.

But in general cases such password reset links come with a token attached to it which has an expiry. Using this mechanism the link becomes unusable after a certain time period. Generally the time limit for the token to expire ranges minutes to days, which is at the sole discretion of the website/portal owners.

The reset mail that you have received might have specified of the time the link will be active.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

That's not good because anyone with that link (note: the token is the most important) can make changes to your password for an unlimited time.

Solution 1: Invalidate the token once the password has been successfully reset.

Solution 2: Make the token expire after some time. Real-world examples often range from 10 minutes to 3 hours.

I'd recommend implementing both of the above.